# face smile detector chrome extension running in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, getusermedia, face-api

Im using face-api to make a chrome extension, that counts the amount of times you smile. Right now I have the detecting and counting all done in the pop up.js. And it works in the chrome extension when I click the icon. However, it only detects the face and counts the number of smiles only when the icon is pressed and the pop up with the camera appears. When closed, it stops detecting the face. But even when the pop up is closed, my camera is still on.

Is there a way, to continue to detect and count the number of smiles I'm making, with the pop up closed, and the pop up will only display the smile count so far when the icon is clicked?

I tried moving my detecting code to the background and send a message of smile counts when icon is clicked to the pop up, however I think browserAction.onClicked.addListener does not work with pop ups. Also my background code is not logging results, probably because there is no camera data?

This is my background code

```
function startVideo() {   navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
    err => console.error(err)   ); } video.addEventListener("playing", () => {   const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);   document.body.append(canvas); 
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height };   faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);

  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
      .withFaceLandmarks()
```

...

Let me know what I can do, thank you!

Comment: The popup scripts run only when the popup is shown. The background script runs in a hidden background page so I don't think it would make sense to run anything visual there. AFAIK the only solution is to open your popup.html in a separate window e.g. via window.open or chrome.windows.create. P.S. you're right about browserAction.onClicked not working when default_popup is declared.

Comment: Is there a way to do it like how the adblocker icon shows 6 ads blocked, but with mine smile detected? yeah I wanted the background to only do the detecting but send the smile count data to the pop up. Thanks, i'll try the popup.html in a separate window too

Comment: if I add a pop up in the background, how will i communicate it to send my smile count values to be displayed in my pop up?

Comment: @wOxxOm when my popup.html runs in a different tab and I navigate away from it, it tends to work slower, detecting the smiles slower. Is it because the tab sleeps when you navigate away? Is the only way to making it faster Enable tab discarding? Also I've read that theres no longer the option for enable tab discarding and stop some tabs from sleeping...what is the best action forwards? Especially if I want to publish to this extension, thank you once again for all your amazing help!